# Convert searched case to simple case else

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I've the following code

```
select * from weeks 
where case
when wet>1000 then wenumber=1
when wet>500 then wenumber=2
when wet>100 then wenumber=3
else wenumber= 22
end
```

it gives me the result of both ( when > 1000 and else )
through my search I understood that it is search case, but
I need to make it a simple case
simply if the first condition were true stop evaluating "else" statement
any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM weeks 
WHERE wenumber = CASE WHEN wet > 1000 THEN 1
                      WHEN wet BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN 2
                      WHEN wet BETWEEN 100 AND 500 THEN 3
                      ELSE 22
                 END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way of doing it

```
select *
from weeks 
where  ( wet>1000 and wenumber = 1 ) or wenumber = 22
```

Comment: Better way when there are only two conditions, when more CASE is more readable

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which column should be compared with result of CASE like:

```
SELECT *
FROM weeks 
WHERE wenumber = (CASE
                     WHEN wet > 1000 THEN 1
                     ELSE 22
                 END)
```